# Imprimir un punto flotante en ensamblador NASM

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel, ensamblador, coma-flotante

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para un curso de la Universidad, nos pidieron calcular el numero Áureo y luego imprimirlo en pantalla, ya contamos con el cálculo del mismo, ahora el inconveniente es que no sabemos como sacar ese número de la `FPU` e imprimirlo como un `ASCII`, hemos utilizado la instrucción `FST/FIST` para almacenarlo en memoria pero a la hora de comprobar su valor con un `debugger` este cambia a su representación en `Hexadecimal`, lo cuál el `CPU` lo transforma en otro valor decimal, si alguien sabe como imprimirlo como un `ASCII` o conoce otra manera de hacerlo se lo agradecería.

Esto es un poco del código que estamos implementando:

```
section .bss

numero_aureo resb 1

section .data

;numeros necesarios para calcular el numero aureo
x   dd  1
y   dd  5.0
z   dd  2


section .text

    global _start

_start:

;calculo del numero aureo

    finit
    fld     dword[y]    ;carga el 5 a la FPU
    fsqrt               ;saca la raiz de 5
    fiadd   dword[x]    ;suma el 1
    fidiv   dword[z]    ;divide entre 2 
    fst     dword[numero_aureo]

esto es lo que me da el debugger:

Breakpoint 4, 0x08048097 in t4 ()

(gdb) info float 

=>R7: Valid   0x3fffcf1bbcdcbfa53e0b +1.618033988749894848        
  R6: Empty   0x00000000000000000000  
  R5: Empty   0x00000000000000000000  
  R4: Empty   0x00000000000000000000  
  R3: Empty   0x00000000000000000000  
  R2: Empty   0x00000000000000000000  
  R1: Empty   0x00000000000000000000  
  R0: Empty   0x00000000000000000000


Status Word:         0x3820                  PE                        

                       TOP: 7

Control Word:        0x037f   IM DM ZM OM UM PM  
                       PC: Extended Precision (64-bits)  
                       RC: Round to nearest

Tag Word:            0x3fff

Instruction Pointer: 0x00:0x00000000  
Operand Pointer:     0x00:0x00000000  
Opcode:              0x0000

(gdb) continue 

Continuing.

Breakpoint 5, 0x0804809d in fin ()  
(gdb) print numero_aureo   
$1 = 1070537661  
(gdb)
```

Comment: Has intentado algo como http://stackoverflow.com/a/29449187/6658955 ? Podrías poner parte de tu código

Comment: La pregunta es, alomejor el problema no es del programa ni la función FST/FIST si no del debugger, que te está tocando los valores, prueba imprmir el valor del registro con la función 'db' y el registro en el que tienes guardado el valor

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, lo siento si no contesté antes, para resolver este problema lo que hice fue correr la coma y redondear el número al entero más cercano, luego con varias funciones agregué el punto para representarlo en pantalla.

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @fredyfx Sí, ahorita no me acuerdo muy bien de como lo solucioné pero la base de la lógica que utilicé fue sacar número por número del `FPU` e ir agregándolo a una "variable" en memoria. Para colocar el punto, como era un número de solo un dígito antes de la coma simplemente se la agregué por medio de otra función en la posición [1] del espacio en memoria y fui corriendo así los demás número de sus posiciones.